# How to move a double in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, double, mips

I'm trying to read a double from the user, then store it in a temporary register, like this:

```
li $v0, 7   #syscall for reading double = 7
syscall
mov.d $t0, $f0  #t0= number of gallons
```

I'm getting an error:

"$t0": operand is of incorrect type

What is the correct type to use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$t0` is not a floating-point register, so you cannot `mov.d` to it. Use one of the other floating-point registers instead (`$f1..$f31`). Since doubles occupy two adjacent floating point registers you should move to one of the even floating-point-registers (`$f2, $f4, ..., $f30`).

---

If you *really* wanted to place the value of `$f0` in `$t0` you'd have to convert it to a single-precision float first and then use `mfc1`:

```
cvt.s.d $f2,$f0   # convert to single-precision (32-bit)
mfc1 $t0,$f2      # copy the single-precision float bit-for-bit to GPR $t0
```

Note that `$t0` will now contain a floating-point number, so it will be useless in integer arithmetic operations.

---

It's also possible to convert the double to an integer and then move it to a GPR:

```
cvt.w.d $f2,$f0   # convert to integer by rounding (according to the currently set rounding mode)
mfc1 $t0,$f2      # copy to GPR $t0
```

So if you originally had `3.14` in `$f0` you'd end up with either `3` or `4` in `$t0` depending on the current rounding mode.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm trying to compare the double value to zero and it's not working. I have `bne $f2, $zero, loop` and it should branch if equal to zero, but I have an error that says "$f2": operand is of incorrect type. How can I compare the value to zero?

Comment: You load the double value you want to compare against (in the case `0.0`) into some other floating point register (let's say `$f2`), then you do a floating point comparison: `c.eq.d $f0,$f2`, and then you can branch based on that comparison with `bc1f` or `bc1t` (e.g. `bc1t f0_is_zero`). I suggest that you download _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_.